# Split Uri with Play Framework 2

Tags: java, playframework

I'm working with **play 2** and the problem is I have to remove the uri with the `\` character.

I get the following error:

[PatternSyntaxException: Unexpected internal error near index 1 \ ^]

And here gives the error:

```
        public static Result index(String url){
    -->     String[] splits = url.split("/");
            String a,b,c;
            a = splits[0];
            b = splits[1];
            c = splits[2];

            return ok(showString.render(a,b,c));
        }
```

The value of url is:

```
example/example2/example3
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Where are you having that code? can you show us some surrounding code. That statement alone cannot throw exception in Java at least.

Comment: I just updated the post with the method of the error and pointed out the line in which the error occurs.

Comment: ya lo solucione yo, era error mio, no del codigo. Thanks @RohitJain